# Why can't CMake not find prefix_path?

Tags: docker, cmake, dependencies

I'm writing a Dockerfile for a container to simulate an environment based on `Ubuntu Xenial` and `ROS Kinetic`. Now, as part of getting the environment up and running, I'll have to run a custom build script. It stops with saying:

```
-- Could not find the required component 'camera_info_manager'. The following CMake 
error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or ch
ange your environment so that it can be found.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_packa
ge):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by
  "camera_info_manager" with any of the following names:

    camera_info_managerConfig.cmake
    camera_info_manager-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "camera_info_manager" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
  or set "camera_info_manager_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
  files.  If "camera_info_manager" provides a separate development package or
  SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  flir_spinnaker_driver/CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/eis/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/eis/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
root@0573de1e074a:/home/eis# echo $CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH 
/opt/ros/kinetic:/usr/share/camera_info_manager/cmake:/usr/share/camera_info_manager
/cmake/camera_info_managerConfig.cmake
root@0573de1e074a:/home/eis#
```

I have installed package `libcamera-info-manager-dev`&`libcamera-info-manager0d` and found `camera_info_managerConfig.cmake` in `/usr/share/camera_info_manager /cmake/` and modified `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` like:

```
export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=$CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH:/usr/share/camera_info_manager/cmake:/usr/share/camera_info_manager
```

I've also added `/usr/share/camera_info_manager` and `/usr/include/camera_info_manager`:

`echo $CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH  /opt/ros/kinetic:/usr/share/camera_info_manager/cmake:/usr/share/camera_info_manager /cmake/camera_info_managerConfig.cmake:/usr/share/camera_info_manager:/usr/include/c amera_info_manager`

but I'm still stuck on this.

What else should I be looking at? Thanks!

Comment: @BitFreak: An installation **prefix** is a common directory where the **whole package** is installed, not the directory just with the package's *config file*. In your case the installation **prefix** is `/usr`, so CMake should find directory with the file `/usr/share/camera_info_manager/cmake/camera_info_managerConfig.cmake` using formulae `<prefix>/(lib/<arch>|lib*|share)/cmake/<name>*` listed in the [find_package algorithm](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/command/find_package.html#search-procedure). If you want to specify directory with the config file, set `camera_info_manager_DIR` var

Comment: @Tsyvarev You are correct, I forgot this environment variable also existed.